# stdscr.getstr() ignore keys, just string

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses

I just need convert entered text(bytes) to string.
But if i on cyrillic press Backspace and some character, python throw me this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 10: invalid continuation byte
```

What i can do?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from re import sub
import curses


chatting = True
cols = 0
lines = 0


def get_msg(stdscr):
    str_text = ""
    while chatting:
        inpwin = curses.newwin(2, 30, 1, 0)
        text = inpwin.getstr()
        str_text = str(text, "utf-8") # this string throw error

        stdscr.addstr(0, 0, str_text)
        stdscr.refresh()


def main(stdscr):
    curses.echo()
    stdscr.scrollok(True)
    global cols
    global lines
    lines, cols = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    get_msg(stdscr)


curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: That *"cyrillic"* hints that your locale may be a problem, e.g., you would have to call `setlocale` in the script to initialize things properly.

Comment: @ThomasDickey no, this does not work.

Comment: @ThomasDickey i think, what python's str() does not recognize the this special(and not needed) key combination. But how i can skip this? I tried ```for ch in text:```, but i can not translate this byte to string properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str_text = str(text, "utf-8")
```

I had to add `errors` argument:

```
str_text = str(text, "utf-8", errors="ignore")
```